# invalid alter table option while modify foreign key

Tags: plsql, foreign-keys, alter-table, alter

I want to modify the update option of one foreign key.
For this I executed this command:

```sql
 alter table testusers.ORDERS
 DROP CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK_2,
 ADD CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK_2 FOREIGN KEY(FK_PRODUCER_ID) REFERENCES testuser.PRODUCER      (producer_id) 
 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If I execute this, there is the following error:

```
 SQL-Fehler: ORA-01735: Ungültige Option ALTER TABLE
 01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
```

Comment: You will need two [alter table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#i2103997) commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no comma separated list for the alter table according to documentation syntax diagram http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJAEDFIB

```
create table orders(order_id number, fk_producer_id number, CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id));

create table producer(producer_id number, CONSTRAINT producer_pk PRIMARY KEY (producer_id));

alter table orders
  ADD CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK_2 FOREIGN KEY( FK_PRODUCER_ID) 
  REFERENCES PRODUCER      (producer_id) ;

alter table orders 
DROP CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK_2;

alter table orders
  ADD CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK_2 FOREIGN KEY( FK_PRODUCER_ID) 
  REFERENCES PRODUCER      (producer_id) ;
```

Ahm, yes, and I could not find any ON UPDATE CASCADE syntax either. But I am sure you can work it out now. Otherwise drop a little comment or post a new question.